# Faster/more idiomatic way to achieve a "map-when"?

Tags: performance, clojure

I would like to implement a function which maps over a sequence of maps and update values when predicates match

Here is a first working draft :

```
(defn update-if
  ([m k pred f]
   (let [init (get m k)]
     (if (and (not-nil? init) (pred init))
           (update m k f)
           m)))
  ([m bindings]
   (reduce-kv
     (fn [agg k v]
       (let [[pred f] v]
         (update-if agg k pred f)))
    m bindings)))

(update-if {:a 1 :b 2} {:a [even? inc] :b [even? dec]}) ;; ==> {:a 1 :b 1}
(update-if {:a 1 :b 2} :b even? dec) ;; ==> {:a 1 :b 1}

(defn map-when
  "Walks a collection of associative collections
  and applies functions based on predicates
  Output :
  (map-when {:a [even? inc] :b [nan? zero]} '({:a 1 :b NaN} {:a 2 :b 7} {:a 4 :b NaN}))
  =
  ({:a 1 :b 0} {:a 3 :b 7} {:a 5 :b 0})"
  ([bindings data]
   (reduce
     (fn [acc row]
       (conj acc (update-if row bindings)))
    '() data))
  ([pred f data]
   (map
     (fn [x]
       (if (and (not-nil? x) (pred x))
             (f x)
             x))
    data)))
```

Not-nil? check is important (here) because it just means data is missing.
The function takes around 2s to perform this on 1 million random `{:a :b}` maps (random gen included) .

I feel odd that no function exists for this in core/core-related library.
Are there some performance hints to improve this ? I tried transient but it does not work on empty lists `'()`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should [look at the specter library](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter).  It probably has what you are looking for.  Example:

```
(def data {:a [{:aa 1 :bb 2}
               {:cc 3}]
           :b [{:dd 4}]})

;; Manual Clojure
(defn map-vals [m afn]
  (->> m (map (fn [[k v]] [k (afn v)])) (into {})))

(map-vals data
  (fn [v]
    (mapv
      (fn [m]
        (map-vals
          m
          (fn [v] (if (even? v) (inc v) v))))
      v)))

;; Specter
(transform [MAP-VALS ALL MAP-VALS even?] inc data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generate just the necessary lambda to maximize reusability.

```
(defn cond-update-fn [clauses]
  (fn [m] 
    (reduce (fn [m [k [pred f]]] 
               (cond-> m
                  (and (contains? m k)
                       (pred (get m k))) (update k f)))
      m 
      clauses)))
```

If your preds and fns are known at compile time writing a macro instead (left as exercise for the reader) gives higher performance because of no pred iteration overhead.

---

Reuse in any context:

```
(def input [{:a 42, :b 42} {:a 42,:b 43}])

(def cond-update 
  (cond-update-fn {:a [even? inc]
                   :b [odd? dec]}))

(map cond-update input)

;-> ({:a 43, :b 42} {:a 43, :b 42})

;; Transducer
(into [] (map cond-update) input)

;-> [{:a 43, :b 42} {:a 43, :b 42}]

;; Standalone

(cond-update {:a 32})
;-> {:a 33}
```